# Handling null / empty string

Tags: .net, null, string

Before .NET 4 is out, we've been doing something like this to check for null / empty string :

```
String s;
if ((s + "").Trim().Length == 0)
{
    //do something
}
```

While the above method works pretty well for us, I know that in .NET 4, we got a `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` method to do the similar thing.

My question is, which one is better? Do we should switch to use the built-in function instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On .NET 4, I'd definitely use the built in method. After all, it says *exactly* what you're trying to do.

If you're stuck before .NET 4, why not use:

```
if (s == null || s.Trim() == "")
```

Or

```
if (s == null || s.Trim().Length == 0)
```

? Both of those say what you want to achieve.

I definitely *wouldn't* use string concatenation here. Performance aside, you're not interested in string concatenation. Whenever you find your code doing something which really isn't part of what you're trying to achieve, you should try to improve it for the sake of readability.

Comment: What's wrong with string concatenation? Is it really that bad?

Comment: @andri: It's fine when you *want* to concatenate strings. But you don't. You're *only* using concatenation to avoid handling null references. That's not good.

Comment: I think I got your point here. But in some cases, we also need to actually process the `Trim`med string (and turn them into empty string if it's `null`). Is concatenation to avoid `null` still a bad idea for that case?

Comment: Forget my previous comment, I've found the answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/416473/coalesce-vs-empty-string-concatenation

Answer (score 2):

I personally use `IsNullOrWhiteSpace`, mostly because using it makes code clearer to read and it handles more cases (the `WhiteSpace` part). It depends on your preferences, because both methods does pretty the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Why not write a helper method to implement what `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` does before .NET 4? Just like

```
public static boolean IsNullOrWhiteSpace(string input)
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) || input.Trim() == string.Empty;
}
```

Don't use concatenation here as Jon said. It's not a good practice for checking null/empty.

Comment: Yes, actually *some* of our implementation does using the helper / extension method (and some other directly using the code like the sample above `:(`).

Comment: @andri It's never late and always worth refactoring. :)